# Compatibility of RAM modules

Tags: memory, compatibility, hardware-rec

I have an old computer with **3 RAM modules** with **1GB each**, as follows:

```
Type: DDR2 
Size: 1024 MBytes 
Manufacturer: Kingston 
Max bandwith: PC2-6400 (400 MHz) 
Reference number: KTC1G-UDIMM
```

Now I want to buy another module to have 4GB, but I don't know which models will work fine with those I already have...

So basically, **which of the features listed above the new module should match** to work properly?

---

NOTE - my motherboard is **GA-P35-DS3L**, and I run [Crucial Scan](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/) it says this:

```
Memory Type: DDR2 PC2-8500, DDR2 PC2-6400, DDR2 PC2-5300, DDR2 (non-ECC)
```

Comment: You should buy one more of what you already have.

Comment: @Moses, that's exactly what I want to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PC2-6400 is the spec, just get RAM at that speed, and you'll be fine, If you're really paranoid replace them all at the same time, that way you know the timings and everything match, you shouldn't have to, but I've seen modules both rated for the same speed not play well because the timings were off.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just want to buy a cheap one to carry on before buying a new motherboard and processor, so I don't mind if the increasing of performace is not masive... So you mean ANY module 1GB and PC2-6400 will work? The 400Mhz is not important?

Comment: the speed is important, but PC2-6400 is a specification, stick to that, it's what's most important

Comment: I just asked because most of the modules I'm seeing online are 800Mhz, so I wanted to be sure a 1GB PC2-6400 800Mhz module will work on my system...

Comment: It's generally advisable as a rule of thumb to match memory best you can, especially with dual channel modules. If you have 3 PC2-6400 modules, try to get memory with matching timings. Its normal for motherboards to support different speeds, but mixing them could be bad.